# c# get value from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#0033cc" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ONE" Text='<%#Eval("REG_ID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#0033cc" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TWO" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkBlue" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="report" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" Text="Report to HR" runat="server" OnClick="report_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Above is the code of my GridView. I want get the value of A and B from the GridView when I click the button. Any ideas how to perform this?

```
  protected void report_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow theClickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    if (theClickedRow != null)
    {
        Label FIRST = theClickedRow.FindControl("ONE") as Label;
        Label SECOND = theClickedRow.FindControl("TWO") as Label;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + FIRST + SECOND + "');", true);

    }
}
```

RESULT I get always : system web ui controlsystem web ui control

Comment: Try this, Label has a Text property which I think is the one you're looking for `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + FIRST.Text + SECOND.Text + "');", true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FIRST` and `SECOND` are Label objects. When you call `"alert('" + FIRST + SECOND + "');"`, you are printing the actual objects instead of the values of these controls.

Label controls have a [`.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property which allows you to access the text content value.

Your code should be changed to the following:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + FIRST.Text + SECOND.Text + "');", true);
```